# Problema con el origen de fecha en Excel

Tags: excel, microsoft-office

mi problema es el siguiente: tengo una tabla de datos con la columna de fecha que toma 3 días, son 1, 11 y 21. Cuando creo una tabla dinámica y aplico filtros por fechas, salen todos los días del 1 al 30 / 31) Solo quiero filtrar de acuerdo con los datos de los días que tengo.

la siguiente imagen muestra la fecha original de mis datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito filtrar, por ejemplo, del 1 de enero al 11 de febrero y que el filtro se aplique de 1999 a 2020, que es el año hasta el que tengo disponible mi información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes intentar agregar segmentación de datos

analizar tabla dinamica-->insertar segmentación de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: se pueden eliminar desde <11-01-20 para abajo todas las opciones bloqueadas del menu desplegable ? para que quede más limpio

Comment: si, eso lo puedes quitar en "ocultar elementos sin datos"

Comment: ahora quisé voler a realizar segmentación de datos y salen solos los meses. Cómo puedo configurar eso?